# Can a GitHub organization owner remove another owner?

Tags: github

Say I make an organization, and set someone else to owner. Will they be able to remove me from that organization? Or are there special elevated perms for the "original" owner?

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is even the right place for this question, but I haven't been able to find anything about this online.

Comment: You can email Github support, they are usually very helpful. Or make a second account a try it? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, once you make a user owner of your organization, user gets all the permissions as you. So, user can remove you from organization.

Github can't recognize you as Original owner. There are only two possible roles, OWNER and MEMBER.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do. If you want them to be able to add/remove other members without giving over full organisation access you try to add a team, add the repositories you want to that team with write access, then make the user a "maintainer" of the team which should allow them to add/remove users and therefore manage write access to particular repositories.

https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/permission-levels-for-an-organization